# Using this interface

Tags: support, code

I am unable to  copy and paste a block of code from MikTex here.

It shows up when I copy, then disappears when I click post your question.

Is that supposed to be what happens. It's kind of long to type it over.

Comment: No, that is definitely not what is supposed to happen, and it's never happened to me. Does the problem still occur?